# Windows Update - translate Update GUID until Update "Microsoft KB" Number?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update, knowledge-base

Am troubleshooting a complete windows update failure - on a brand new install, standalone Windows 2012 Server Essentials. Zero config, no existing infrastructure, "straight out of the box" setup.

Windows Update never gets going at all - but strangly have installed it in the past from this exact install media on this exact server.
Yet, now it fails.  The only rational reason I can imagine is a new update has recently been released that breaks windows update for this OS version on a fresh install.

The last entries from the WindowsUpdate.log are:

```
2017-01-18  15:11:14:840     412    1424    Agent   WARNING: Failed to evaluate Installable rule, updateId = {E66A6795-3E20-43ED-9C66-FE134EEEECBC}.200, hr = 80070057
2017-01-18  15:11:19:324     412    1424    Agent   Bundled update {FBEC0F80-9F87-4B42-BA14-2BBE7148322A}.203 is missing extended metadata
2017-01-18  15:11:19:324     412    1424    Agent   Bundle contains children which has no localextended metadata and thus is invalid.
2017-01-18  15:11:19:324     412    1424    Agent   Update {B27CF4B3-0B7D-475D-9129-883E6DED6182}.203 is not a valid bundle. Not returning it.
```

Question: Does the above mean that there is a specific invalid/corrupted Update that the server is trying to fetch?

If so, is it possible to translate the hex/guid update ID codes ({B27CF4B3...}) into Microsoft KB Update ID?  So one may research the specific update that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution, to solve under underlying windows update problem, was:

1) To use WSUS Offline, and download all updates for Win2k Server
2) Using a Windows 10 machine, use NTLite to integrate all updates offline into the Win2k Server Install Media
3) Reinstall server, with the Patched Install Media.

Note: the above process fails on a windows 7 machine, a windows 10 machine was required to run the NTLite Process.